# Можно ли решить через статические методы

Tags: javascript, методы, декоратор

Можно ли данное задание решить используя статические методы?Можно не решать) просто интересно.Но если есть желание и время,то буду рад

Создайте декоратор makeCaching(f), который берет функцию f и возвращает обертку, которая кеширует её результаты.

В этой задаче функция f имеет только один аргумент, и он является числом.

При первом вызове обертки с определенным аргументом – она вызывает f и запоминает значение.
При втором и последующих вызовах с тем же аргументом возвращается запомненное значение.

```
function f(x) {
  return Math.random()*x;
}

function makeCaching(f) {
  var cache = {};

  return function(x) {
    if (!(x in cache)) {
      cache[x] = f.call(this, x);
    }
    return cache[x];
  };

}

f = makeCaching(f);

var a = f(1);
var b = f(1);
alert( a == b ); // true (значение закешировано)

b = f(2);
alert( a == b ); // false, другой аргумент => другое значение
```

Comment: `f.call(this, x);` - ??

Comment: "// true (значение закешировано)" - `a` и `b` - числа. Кeшируй, не кeшируй, они все равно будут одинаковыми для одного и того же `х`.

Comment: А что не так тут: f.call(this, x);? У нас же один аргумент если вы о контексте конечно

Comment: зачем здесь `.call(this`?

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl, `alert( a == 1 ); // true (т.к. не ссылки сравниваются)`

Comment: Ну так это в любом декораторе используется либо Call  либо apply  для запоминания контекста, на случай если переменная  получаемая функцией будет перезаписана,разве не так  ?

Comment: я в этой фразе понимаю каждое слово в отдельности

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
    function f(x) {
        return  x
    }
    function makeCaching(_f) {
        var cache = {}
        return function (x) {
            if (!(x in cache)) {
                cache[x] = [_f(x)]
            }
            return cache[x]
        };

    }
    let f2 = makeCaching(f)
    var a = f2(1)
    var b = f2(1)
    var c = f2(1)
    console.log(a)          //[1]
    console.log(a === b)    // true
    console.log(b === c)    // true
    console.log(a === [1])  // false
}
console.log('---')
{
    function f(x) {
        return  x
    }
    function makeCaching(_f) {
        var cache = {}

        return function (x) {
            if (!(x in cache)) {
                cache[x] = _f.call(this, x)
            }
            return cache[x]
        };

    }
    let f2 = makeCaching(f)
    var a = f2(1)
    var b = f2(1)
    var c = f2(1)
    console.log(a)        // 1
    console.log(a === b)  // true
    console.log(b === c)  // true
    console.log(a === 1)  // true
}
```